# How add a DialogFragment in a normal Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

This source showed `DialogFragment` created new `Fragment` and blocked all screen (`FragmentActivity`). I need to add a `Dialog`  in the  `Fragment` so that when I can scroll the screen and the `DialogFragment` will not interfere. Current code:

```
FragmentManager fm = fa.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            // create dlg fragment
            DialogFragment fragment = new DialogFragment();
            // show the dialog.
            fragment.show(fm, "android:switcher:888889:1"); // "android:switcher:888889:1" - existing fragment!
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to add Dialog in the "fragment" Then I can scroll the screen
>   and FragmentDialog will not interfere

A normal `DialogFragment`(or normal `Dialog`) will not work for what you want. Insted you could make use of nested `Fragments`. More precisely you'll need to modify your current `Fragment`'s view from the `ViewPager` to wrap their current layout with a `RelativeLayout` or a `FrameLayout` along with adding another container(a `FrameLayout`) on top of the content.

That extra `FrameLayout` on top will be used as a `Dialog` holder(so the `Dialog` will appear as floating on top of the normal content) and to this container you'll add a `Fragment` to represent the `Dialog`(a normal `Fragment`, not a `DialogFragment`). You'll then be able to swipe the `ViewPager` even with your fake `Dialog` showing.

Also, keep in mind that swiping the `ViewPager` although a `Dialog` is showing on the screen, might be counter intuitive for the user.